# Center across selection doesn't work on "smaller range" but only on "bigger range"

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you're doing well. I am reaching out to the Stack Overflow community as I am currently experiencing beginner problem in programming in VBA in Excel. I am indeed trying to shorten and harmonize excels processes in my company.

**CONTEXT**
Among other commands, I am trying to program a macro to Center across selection (that can be pretty useful and which is a pain to right click go to Format etc.). I found the code online and somehow it works to some extent.

**PROBLEM**
Step 1
I select some cells. I run the macro (see code below). It centers across selection.
Step 2
I select a greater range of cells. It still center across selection.
Step 3
I select a smaller range of cells. *It doesn't center across selection. It keeps the widest range used on this particular set of cells.*

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR**
I tried using the Selection.ClearFormats command ; didn't work (maybe not used well).

**CODE**

```
Sub center_across_selection()
'
' center_across_selection Macro
'
' Touche de raccourci du clavier: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    With Selection
      If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        'converts regular text to centered across selection
        Else
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

[first_step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sOmP.png)

[second_step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkfiV.png)

Comment: A screenshot of the "failed" range would be useful here.

Comment: Does the "first step" and "second step" help?

Comment: Seems like each individual cell will get the "center across selection" alignment, and if you set that value on cells immediately next to cells which *already* have that setting (but might have no content), Excel will automatically extend the "selection" to include those other cells.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What would be a solution then, as clearing formats of the cells doesn't work for me? Can you come up with an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like each individual cell will get the "center across selection" alignment, and if you set that value on cells immediately next to cells which already have that setting (but have no content), Excel will automatically extend the "selection" to include those other cells.

Here's some code which will show the formats just below the selected cells:

```
Sub center_across_selection()
    Dim c As Range
    With Selection
        'show alignment "before"
        For Each c In .Cells
            c.Offset(1, 0) = c.HorizontalAlignment
        Next c
        Debug.Print .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        Else
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End If
        'show alignment "after"
        For Each c In .Cells
            c.Offset(2, 0) = c.HorizontalAlignment
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

As for a fix, you could check the cell immediately to the right of the last cell in your selection - if it's set as "center across selection" then set it to something else.

```
Sub center_across_selection2()
    Dim c As Range, rNext As Range
    With Selection
        If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        Else
            'check whether the next cell to the right has CAS and is empty
            Set rNext = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1)
            If rNext.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection _
                                         And Len(rNext.Value) = 0 Then
                rNext.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            End If
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is 100% correct and it gets me **every** time. If you've CAS once then try to shrink the range manually, you _must_ assign some other alignment to the _whole selection_ first, then you can CAS for your smaller range.

Comment: Thank you so much. How would you check also cells to the left as you pointed out? Sorry, real beginner here. Should I pate what you wrote but with offset(0,-1)? and call it rPrevious for example?

Comment: I just tested, and I don't think it "looks" to the left for adjacent CAS formatting, only to the right.  It does matter whether the cell to the right has a value, so I added a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function to recursively check cells to the right of the selection:

```
Sub center_across_selection()
    With Selection
        If .Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then resetAlignment (.Offset(0, 1))

        If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        'converts regular text to centered across selection
        Else
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End If
    End With

End Sub


Function resetAlignment(rng As Range)
    rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    If rng.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection Then resetAlignment (rng.Offset(0, 1))
End Function
```